# Set input date local with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that can be configured to use many languages ('en', 'fr', 'it'), my question is: how can I set the format of the date and time in input of type date or datetime-local dynamically with javascript to match the language of the application and not the language of the browser or the OS?

Comment: What do you mean by "match the language of the application"?

Comment: Think of it as a variable: if ('en') else if ('fr') and so on

Comment: Well it's next to impossible to help without seeing your code. You're likely to get people helping if you post it.

Comment: Check out momentJS. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: I do not write any code yet. What I mean here: there is any way to set the local of the input programmatically with javascript?

Comment: @JeremyThille I need to customize the input field not the strings

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff same response as JeremyThille